# React prop validation for date objects

Tags: reactjs

**What is the currently preferred way to validate a `Date` prop in react?**

Right now I'm using: `React.PropTypes.object`

This, however, is now failing the [forbid-prop-types](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/forbid-prop-types.md) lint rule. Should I use a `shape` or is there some better way?

Answer (score 628, accepted):

Pretty sure you could use `PropTypes.instanceOf(Date)`

Comment: Yep that did it! Not sure how I missed that in the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html).

Comment: It likely to be described in https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html

Comment: Could the same method be used for `moment` objects?

Comment: @jlouzado You've probably figured out what you're going to do already, but this is an option: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-moment-proptypes

Comment: @RiverTam I actually just used `PropTypes.instanceOf(moment)` and it worked. That code initially didn't work because my `propTypes` definition inside the `Component` wasn't marked `static`.

is there any extra benefit that `react-moment-proptypes` provides?

Comment: Most importantly, if it works for you, it works for you. Your solution is probably the optimal solution. That said, I tend to prefer packages over my own solutions in many cases because the person who wrote the packages is almost always more confident in their ability to write and maintain the solution than I am, plus it offloads the cognitive burden onto the package maintainer. Now, if for whatever reason the `instanceOf` solution stops working, the package will more likely be updated than your own code. But, again, if it works for you, it works for you.

Comment: Also, to be clear, I've never personally used that package so I can't make a case for using that package in particular.

Comment: @RiverTam relying on another dependency for the sake of a false sense of security is not a good idea. Especially for something as simple as `instanceOf`, considering it's not OP's own solution, it's a part of the library. i.e it's maintained on github. There's no need to use 2 libraries just to use one function of it.

Comment: I got 
```Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `selectedDate` of type `Object` supplied to `MyComponent`, expected instance of `Date`.```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me

```
PropTypes.oneOfType([
    PropTypes.string,
    PropTypes.number,
    PropTypes.instanceOf(Date),
]).isRequired
```